# Differences between lexical features and orthographic features in NLP?

Tags: nlp

Features are used for model training and testing. What are the differences between lexical features and orthographic features in Natural Language Processing? Examples preferred.

Answer (score 7):

I am not aware of such a distinction, and most of the time when people talk about lexical features they talk about using the word itself, in contrast to only using other features, ie its part-of-speech.

[Here is an example of a paper that means "whole word orthograph" when they say lexical features](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D09-1119)

One could venture that *orthographic* could mean something more abstract than the sequence of characters themselves, for example whether the sequence is capitalized / titlecased / camelcased / etc. But we already have the useful and clearly understood *shape feature* denomination for that.

As such, I would recommend distinguishing features like this:

**lexical features**:
whole word, prefix/suffix (various lengths possible), stemmed word, lemmatized word

**shape features**:
uppercase, titlecase, camelcase, lowercase

**grammatical and syntactic features**:
POS, part of a noun-phrase, head of a verb phrase, complement of a prepositional phrase, etc...

This is not an exhaustive list of possible features and feature categories, but it might help you categorizing linguistic features in a clearer and more widely-accepted way.

Comment: orthographic feature is sort of shape feature, I think.

Comment: Any substantial proof? Could you point us to a paper/article that talks about orthographic feature. Prima facie google search didn't help

Comment: @ChaitanyaBapat: Are you asking me or @DehengYe?

Comment: To @DehengYe But found the answer orthographic features are basically the rules the written languages follow. For example, names are capitalized in english. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthography